# How can I use BeautifulSoup to get deeply nested div values?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get the values of deeply nested `<span>` elements in a DOM structure that looks like this:

```
<div class="panda">
    <div class="that">
        <ul class="foo">
            <li class="bar">
                <div class="hi">
                    <p class="bye">
                        <span class="cheese">Cheddar</span>
```

The problem with

`soup.findAll("span", {"class": "cheese"})`

is that there are hundreds of span elements on the page with class "cheese" so I need to filter them by class "panda". I need to get a list of values like `["Cheddar", "Parmesan", "Swiss"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css selectors:

```
[e.get_text() for e in soup.select('.panda .cheese')]
```

Or, if you prefer `find_all`:

```
# Calling a soup or tag is the same as find_all

[e.get_text() for panda in soup('div', {'class': 'panda'}) 
              for e in panda('span', {'class': 'cheese'})]
```

Comment: Almost there. This returns the full tag and inner html like `<span class="cheese">Parmesan</span>`. I just need the value `Parmesan` and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I had to install BeautifulSoup4 because I was getting a typeerror at first. Thanks, now it works.

Comment: Could you please describe your answer in more detail? I don't understand your answer in full detail :,(