# Using Python to Scrape Nested Divs and Spans in Twitter?

Tags: python, html, twitter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the likes and retweets from the results of a Twitter search.

After running the Python below, I get an empty list, `[]`.  I'm not using the Twitter API because it doesn't look at the tweets by hashtag this far back.

The code I'm using is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://twitter.com/search?q=%23bangkokbombing%20since%3A2015-08-10%20until%3A2015-09-30&src=typd&lang=en'
r  = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
all_likes = soup.find_all('span', class_='ProfileTweet-actionCountForPresentation')
print(all_likes)
```

I can successfully save the html to file using this code.  It is missing large amounts of information when I search the text, such as the class names I am looking for...

So (part of) the problem is apparently in accurately accessing the source code.

```
 filename = 'newfile2.txt'
 with open(filename, 'w') as handle:
      handle.writelines(str(data))
```

This screenshot shows the span that I'm trying to scrape.

[image: Screenshot of exactly the span and content I am trying to scrape.]

I've looked at this question, and others like it, but I'm not quite getting there.
[How can I use BeautifulSoup to get deeply nested div values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355051/how-can-i-use-beautifulsoup-to-get-deeply-nested-div-values)

Comment: *Thank you* for a) knowing that twitter has an API and b) explaining why you're not using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your GET request returns valid HTML but with no tweet elements in the #timeline element. However, adding a user agent to the request headers seems to remedy this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://twitter.com/search?q=%23bangkokbombing%20since%3A2015-08-10%20until%3A2015-09-30&src=typd&lang=en'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
all_likes = soup.find_all('span', class_='ProfileTweet-actionCountForPresentation')
print(all_likes)
```

Comment: Thank you.  That solves the first part of my problem.  I will go back to working on this now that I'm actually scraping the site and start a new question if I run into different problems.