# Using Python to edit the timestamps in a list? Convert POSIX to readable format using a function

Tags: python, web-scraping, timestamp, list-comprehension

SECOND EDIT:

Finished snippet for adjusting timezones and converting format.  See correct answer below for details leading to this solution.

```
tzvar = int(input("Enter the number of hours you'd like to add to the timestamp:"))
tzvarsecs = (tzvar*3600)
print (tzvarsecs)

def timestamp_to_str(timestamp):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y')

timestamps = soup('span', {'class': '_timestamp js-short-timestamp '})
dtinfo = [timestamp["data-time"] for timestamp in timestamps]
times = map(int, dtinfo)
adjtimes = [x+tzvarsecs for x in times]
adjtimesfloat = [float(i) for i in adjtimes]
dtinfofloat = [float(i) for i in dtinfo]
finishedtimes = [x for x in map(timestamp_to_str, adjtimesfloat)]
originaltimes = [x for x in map(timestamp_to_str, dtinfofloat)]
```

END SECOND EDIT

---

EDIT:

This code allows me to scrape the POSIX time from the HTML file and then add a number of hours entered by the user to the original value.  Negative numbers will also work to subtract hours.  The user will be working in whole hours as the changes are specifically to adjust for timezones.

```
tzvar = int(input("Enter the number of hours you'd like to add to the timestamp:"))
tzvarsecs = (tzvar*3600)
print (tzvarsecs)

timestamps = soup('span', {'class': '_timestamp js-short-timestamp '})
dtinfo = [timestamp["data-time"] for timestamp in timestamps]
times = map(int, dtinfo)
adjtimes = [x+tzvarsecs for x in times]
```

All that is left is a reverse of a function like the one suggested below.  How do I convert each POSIX time in the list to a readable format using a function?

END EDIT

---

---

The code below creates a csv file containing data scraped from a saved Twitter HTML file.

Twitter converts all the timestamps to the user's local time in the browser.  I would like to have an input option for the user to adjust the timestamps by a certain number of hours so that the data for the tweet reflects the tweeter's local time.

I'm currently scraping an element called `'title'` that is a part of each permalink.  I could just as easily scrape the POSIX time from each tweet instead.

```
title="2:29 PM - 28 Sep 2015"
```

vs

```
data-time="1443475777" data-time-ms="1443475777000"
```

How would I edit the following piece so it added a variable entered by the user to each timestamp?  I don't need help with requesting input, I just need to know how to apply it to the list of timestamps after the input is passed to python.

```
timestamps = soup('a', {'class': 'tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip'})
datetime = [timestamp["title"] for timestamp in timestamps]
```

---

Other questions related to this code/project.

[Fix encoding error with loop in BeautifulSoup4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051723/fix-encoding-error-with-loop-in-beautifulsoup4)

[Focusing in on specific results while scraping Twitter with Python and Beautiful Soup 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006682/focusing-in-on-specific-results-while-scraping-twitter-with-python-and-beautiful)

[Using Python to Scrape Nested Divs and Spans in Twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912889/using-python-to-scrape-nested-divs-and-spans-in-twitter)

---

Full code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
import csv
import re
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

url = input("Enter the name of the file to be scraped:")
with open(url, encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(infile, "html.parser")

#url = 'https://twitter.com/search?q=%23bangkokbombing%20since%3A2015-08-10%20until%3A2015-09-30&src=typd&lang=en'
#headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
#r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#data = r.text.encode('utf-8')
#soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

names = soup('strong', {'class': 'fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id'})
usernames = [name.contents for name in names]

handles = soup('span', {'class': 'username js-action-profile-name'})
userhandles = [handle.contents[1].contents[0] for handle in handles]  
athandles = [('@')+abhandle for abhandle in userhandles]

links = soup('a', {'class': 'tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip'})
urls = [link["href"] for link in links]
fullurls = [permalink for permalink in urls]

timestamps = soup('a', {'class': 'tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip'})
datetime = [timestamp["title"] for timestamp in timestamps]

messagetexts = soup('p', {'class': 'TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text'}) 
messages = [messagetext for messagetext in messagetexts]  

retweets = soup('button', {'class': 'ProfileTweet-actionButtonUndo js-actionButton js-actionRetweet'})
retweetcounts = [retweet.contents[3].contents[1].contents[1].string for retweet in retweets]

favorites = soup('button', {'class': 'ProfileTweet-actionButtonUndo u-linkClean js-actionButton js-actionFavorite'})
favcounts = [favorite.contents[3].contents[1].contents[1].string for favorite in favorites]

images = soup('div', {'class': 'content'})
imagelinks = [src.contents[5].img if len(src.contents) > 5 else "No image" for src in images]

#print (usernames, "\n", "\n", athandles, "\n", "\n", fullurls, "\n", "\n", datetime, "\n", "\n",retweetcounts, "\n", "\n", favcounts, "\n", "\n", messages, "\n", "\n", imagelinks)

rows = zip(usernames,athandles,fullurls,datetime,retweetcounts,favcounts,messages,imagelinks)

rownew = list(rows)

#print (rownew)

newfile = input("Enter a filename for the table:") + ".csv"

with open(newfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(['Usernames', 'Handles', 'Urls', 'Timestamp', 'Retweets', 'Favorites', 'Message', 'Image Link'])
    for row in rownew:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code as example, the var `datetime` store a list of string dates. So let's dissect the process in 3 steps, just for comprehension.

Example

```
>>> datetime = [timestamp["title"] for timestamp in timestamps]
>>> print(datetime)
['2:13 AM - 29 Sep 2015', '2:29 PM - 28 Sep 2015', '8:04 AM - 28 Sep 2015']
```

**First step:** convert it to a Python [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

```
>>> datetime_obj = datetime.strptime('2:13 AM - 29 Sep 2015', '%H:%M %p - %d %b %Y')
>>> print(datetime_obj)
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 29, 2, 13)
```

**Second step:** convert datetime object to a Python [structured time object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple)

```
>>> to_time = struct_date.timetuple()
>>> print(to_time)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=29, tm_hour=2, tm_min=13, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=272, tm_isdst=-1)
```

**Third step:** convert sturctured time object to [`time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) using [`time.mktime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime)

```
>>> timestamp = time.mktime(to_time)
>>> print(timestamp)
1443503580.0
```

All together now.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

...
def str_to_ts(str_date):
    return time.mktime(datetime.strptime(str_date, '%H:%M %p - %d %b %Y').timetuple())

datetimes = [timestamp["title"] for timestamp in timestamps]
times = [i for i in map(str_to_ts, datetimes)]
```

PS: datetime is a bad choice for variable name. Specially in this context. :-)

**Update**

To apply a function to each value of list:

```
def add_time(timestamp, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0):
    return timestamp + seconds + (minutes * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60)

datetimes = [timestamp["title"] for timestamp in timestamps]
times = [add_time(i, 5, 0, 0) for i in datetimes]
```

**Update 2**

To convert a timestamp to string formatted date:

```
def timestamp_to_str(timestamp):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%H:%M:%S %m/%d/%Y')
```

Example:

```
>>> from time import time
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> timestamp_to_str(time())
'17:01:47 08/29/2016'
```

Comment: I can just as easily scrape the POSIX time from twitter, as described above.  I don't need to convert the timestamp from one format to another.  I need to know how to add a certain number of hours to each timestamp in the list.  It does seem like it would be easier using the POSIX format.  So, for example, how would I add 17 hours, or 61200, seconds to each item in the list?

Comment: The `str_to_ts` function is the opposite of what I was looking for.  Now that I've added the 61200 seconds to each POSIX time, how do I convert it back into a hh:mm:ss MM/DD/YYYY  format?

Comment: Thanks Mauro, I'm getting an error when applying it to the POSIX times.  Each field in the csv shows `<function timestamp_to_str at 0x0000000000177F28>` instead of the corrected/converted times.

Comment: `finishedtimes = [x for x in map(timestamp_to_str, adjtimes)]`
`originaltimes = [x for x in map(timestamp_to_str, dtinfo)]`  This gives me an error that it requires a float.

Comment: Try to convert the adjtimes and the dtinfo to float.

Comment: I did just that, code edited above.  Thanks for all your help Mauro!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was thinking but not sure if this is what you're after:

```
>>> timestamps = ["1:00 PM - 28 Sep 2015", "2:00 PM - 28 Sep 2016", "3:00 PM - 29 Sep 2015"]
>>> datetime = dict(enumerate(timestamps))
>>> datetime
{0: '1:00 PM - 28 Sep 2015',
 1: '2:00 PM - 28 Sep 2016',
 2: '3:00 PM - 29 Sep 2015'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for `datetime.timedelta` ([documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)). You can convert your inputs into `datetime.datetime` objects in various ways, for example,

```
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1443475777)
```

Then you can perform arithmetic on them with `timedelta` objects. A `timedelta` just represents a change in time. You can construct one with an `hours` argument like so:

```
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

And then `timestamp + delta` will give you another `datetime` one hour in the future. Subtraction will work as well, as will other arbitrary time intervals.